# How to set predicate for a string attribute holding integer value in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, predicate

How to set predicate for a string attribute holding integer value in core data to get the in-between values in integer.
I am using compound predicate for multiple conditions and a piece of code follows..

```
NSPredicate *categoryPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"rating >= %@ AND rating <= %@",ratingFrom.text,ratingTo.text];
[compoundPredicateArray addObject: categoryPredicate ];
```

"rating" attribute is of type string in database. I need to get the rating between the given range in the ratingFrom & ratingTo textfields.

"1" to "10" should fetch all ratings in between 1 to 10.how can I achieve this, without changing the attribute type to number.

Any help appreciated..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am not confirm but try this

convert your values in `NSString` and put this code

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"string CONTAINS[c] %@",searchText];
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. it only checks whether it contains that particular element.But i need to get the range in-between.Anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should change this attribute to be a number rather than a string.  But if that's not possible, the following should force CoreData (or rather SQLite) to treat it as a number:

```
NSPredicate *categoryPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"add:to:(rating,0) >= %d AND add:to:(rating,0) <= %d",ratingFrom.text.intValue,ratingTo.text.intValue];
```

Comment: I get this done by changing the attribute to number. But i tried your suggestion, it is not working .

Answer (score -1):

you can try BETWEEN expression:

> BETWEEN The left-hand expression is between, or equal to either of,
>   the values specified in the right-hand side. The right-hand side is a
>   two value array (an array is required to specify order) giving upper
>   and lower bounds. For example, 1 BETWEEN { 0 , 33 }, or $INPUT BETWEEN
>   { $LOWER, $UPPER }. In Objective-C, you could create a BETWEEN
>   predicate as shown in the following example:

So your code should look like this:

```
NSPredicate *betweenPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"rating BETWEEN %@", @[ratingFrom, ratingTo]];
```

ratingFrom, ratingTo should be NSNumber instances if rating is NSNumber.